# Parsing request body data into object in Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to parse a request body into an object (I am using Java Spring boot).

This is how my controller looks like:

```java
public class UserController {
    @PutMapping("/lock/{id}")
    public Optional<User> lockUser(@PathVariable Long id, @Validated @RequestBody UserLockRequest user) {
        return userService.lockUser(id, user);
    }
}
```

My `UserService` looks like this:

```java
public Optional<User> lockUser(Long userId, UserLockRequest userLockRequest) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);

    user.get().setLocker(userLockRequest.getLocker());
    userRepository.save(user.get());
    return user;
}
```

And my request class `UserLockRequest` looks like this:

```java
public class UserLockRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private Locker locker;

    public Locker getLocker() {
        return locker;
    }

    public void setLocker(Locker locker) {
        this.locker = locker;
    }
}
```

And my request looks like this:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8081/user/lock/8' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "locker_id": "1"
}'
```

My `User` entity contains `locker` field:

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "locker_id")
private Locker locker;
```

I can see that `userLockRequest.getLocker()` in the `UserService` is always null.

I am trying to assign a `Locker` to a `User` object and save it in the database.

I am not sure how to map `locker_id` from the PUT request to `UserLockRequest` which I use for accepting the request.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your JSON says `locker_id` but the name of the property is just `locker`. Note also that you should generally decouple the Web DTOs from your service interfaces; this translation is the controller's fundamental job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get `Locker` from the database and assign it to the `User`. In order to achieve this you need a couple of changes:

```java
public class UserLockRequest {
    private long locker_id;  // so that it matches your JSON, but it should really be "lockerId" and you should update your JSON

    // getter / setter
}
```

Then you need to adjust your `UserService` code as well to get the `Locker` from the database:

```java
public Optional<User> lockUser(Long userId, UserLockRequest userLockRequest) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    Locker locker = lockerService.getById(userLockRequest.getLockerId());

    user.get().setLocker(locker);
    userRepository.save(user.get());
    return user;
}
```

I assumed you have a `LockerService` with a method returning a `Locker` given its ID.

Finally, avoid using `Optional.get()` without checking that the `Optional` is not empty, otherwise, you might get a `NoSuchElementException`. You could do something along the following lines instead:

```java
public User lockUser(Long userId, UserLockRequest userLockRequest) {
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userId);
    Locker locker = lockerService.getById(userLockRequest.getLockerId());

    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        User user = optionalUser.get();
        user.setLocker(locker);
        userRepository.save(user.);
        return user;
    } else {
        // throw some custom exception or just return null, it is your decision
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I assume

1. you have a User entity and a Lock entity and you need to tag a Lock entity against an user entity
2. You have JpaRepository interfaces for both User and Lock entity.
3. You have lombok dependency in your project

If that's correct, below is a solution I would implement. This helps in better
API design and separating the responsibilities between Controller and service classes.

1. Define `UserLockRequest` request body class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserLockRequest{
   
   @NotNull
   @NotBlank
   private int userId;

   @NotNull 
   @NotBlank
   private long lockerId;
}
```

2. `UserService` class. I use constructor based injection as recommended by spring.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final LockerRepository lockerRepository;
    
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, LockerRepository lockerRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.lockerRepository = lockerRepository;
    }

    public User lockUser(UserLockRequest userLockRequest) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser =
                userRepository.findById(userLockRequest.getUserId());
        Optional<Locker> locker = lockerRepository.findById(userLockRequest.getLockerId());

        if (optionalUser.isPresent() && locker.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            user.setLocker(locker.get());
            userRepository.save(user);
            return user;
        } else {
            // Error handling is upto you based on what requirement you have
        }
    }
}
```

3. `UserController` class

```
public class UserController {
    @PutMapping("/lock")
    public Optional<User> lockUser(@Validated @RequestBody UserLockRequest userLockRequest) {
        return userService.lockUser(userLockRequest);
    }
}
```

4. Now below is how your http call looks like

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8081/user/lock/ \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "user_id": 8,
    "locker_id":"1"
}'
```